# Drupal 7 and jQuery Update module

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to upgrade my jQuery in Drupal 7 by installing the jQuery Update module. So far it seems like it's working, but I find the module FAQ a bit puzzling. It says this:

- Drupal 5 to jQuery 1.2.6
- Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2
- Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.1, 1.7.1, or 1.8.2 (site administrator's choice), and jQuery UI 1.8.11
- Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.1/1.7.1/1.8.2, 1.9.1, 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.1 (in dev branch 7.x-2.x-dev)
- Drupal 8: TBD

What does "site administrator's choice" mean? I don't see any config options in the jQuery Update module. Where would I specify this option?

Answer (score 1):

I think it just means that you can choose between different versions, as far as I remember on `Drupal7` you can choose between the listed versions.

A little side note, if you're using `Views` module, `jQuery 1.8.*` will break the interface for creating views, I reccomend you to use up to `1.7.*`, this was the version that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid problem... I didn't realize you can change config options under Admin > Configuration, not Admin > Modules. I see that I can change to 1.8 now. Thanks for the Views tip. Luckily, I don't think I'm using that module.